# REACT NATIVE MAPS : I am unable to render markers for my react native map?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Component, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { fb } from "./Firebase/data";
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
      nodes: []
    }

  componentDidMount(){
        const db = fb.firestore()
          .collection('nodes')
          .get()
          .then( snapshot => {
            const nodes = []
            snapshot.forEach( doc =>{
              const data = doc.data()
              nodes.push(data)
            });
         this.setState({
          nodes : nodes
        })
      });
    }

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.nodes.lat)
      return (
        <MapView
        style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 28.5450,
          longitude: 77.1926,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0039922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0039421,
        }} >

{this.state.nodes.map((marker, index) => {
      <Mapview.Marker 
        key = {index}
        coordinate = {{ latitude : marker.lat}, 
                      { longitude : marker.lon}}
        title = { marker.location }
        />
        } 
        )
      }

        </MapView>
      );
    }
}
console.disableYellowBox = true;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
  mapStyle: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
})
```

This is my parent code for the react native project. If needed I can also show the export fb code but I am confident it is working

Can someone please tell me what's wrong here since the data from firebase is available on the console when I don't invoke Mapview but just when I invoke it Mapview the console shows Array [].

I just want to render the markers on the map

Answer (score 0):

You did not return anything on map :

Wrong : `this.state.nodes.map(()=>{})`,

True : `this.state.nodes.map(()=>())`

True v2 : `this.state.nodes.map(()=>{ return ... })`

Final code should look like :

```js
{this.state.nodes.map((marker, index) => (
  <Mapview.Marker
    key={index}
    coordinate={({ latitude: marker.lat }, { longitude: marker.lon })}
    title={marker.location}
  />
))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did these changes but it's still not rendering the markers. I think the issue is the console is showing Array [ ] when I am logging the (this.state.nodes) part in the render block.

Comment: @RiddhijitChattopadhyay What do you mean by invoking Mapview? As i udnerstood you can fetch nodes from firebase and see them in console. But after you take some action, node state set to empty array?

Comment: Yes. I set the return to null and the logged the array and it was showing the fetched nodes but when I set up the mapview and the markers the same log showed an empty array.

Comment: Are you sure that some other component is NOT overwriting nodes? or mutating it?

Comment: I am not sure. But I also tried to just render the values directly and they were rendering without any issue.